# Class name must be a valid object or a string error while voting advance poll

Tags: userpoints, rating

We have some features where we are awarding X points to user on action ex: like a story.

For like functionality we are using [rate module](http://drupal.org/project/rate) and to award points to user using `userpoints module`.

By using `voting rules` it works perfectly but it conflict with`Advance poll` module and in result poll functionality is not working.

So now, I am looking for work around to achieve below functionality-

- likes on story(node)
- voting on poll (developed using advance poll module)

Comment: Resolved module conflict issue by defining entity type for `advpoll`